# How rename files with the same number in the name in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, filesystemobject

I need to list files from two different folders that relate to each other. When there are more than 2 files, excel messes up the sequence and I have to manually organize them in the spreadsheet. I started renaming the files in the folder, viewing those that have the same ending and assigning a number from 1 to 10 at the beginning, that way vba understands the sequence and lists them without problems. Is there any chance of doing this process, renaming the files, directly through vba? Recognizing the relationship between two files with the same ending?

my code:

```
Sub Listar_NNA_RE()

Dim oFSO As Object
Dim oFolder As Object
Dim oFolder_NNA As Object
Dim oFile As Object
Dim lin01 As Integer
Dim arquivos() As String
Dim lCtr As Long

lin01 = 8

    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\RE")
    Set oFolder_NNA = oFSO.GetFolder(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\NNA")
    
    For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
        Cells(lin01, 7) = oFile.Name
        Cells(lin01, 3) = oFile.Name
        
        lin01 = lin01 + 1
        
    Next oFile
    
    For Each oFile In oFolder_NNA.Files
        Cells(lin01, 3) = oFile.Name
        
        lin01 = lin01 + 1
    Next oFile
        
End Sub
```

Comment: You can use the `File.Name` property to get and set the name of a file. You can collect all of the File Objects into a collection, analyze the names using expressions and then output the new names to the files. By collecting the files into a collection before making changes, you also ensure that you don't re-re-name files as you go.

Comment: You might get more useful input if you show us some examples of the file names you have, and show how they should be listed.

Comment: How are the files in the two folders related for example?